# PlotRange change the AxesStyle

Tags: plotting

I want to `Plot` a fancy graph, but I found a strange behaivor using `PlotRange` and `AxesStyle`. When I `Plot` my graph with `PlotRange -> {{-0.39, 3.5}, {4.5, 10.5}}` the `AxesStyle` works, when I try with a number less than -0.39 the `AxesStyle` don't work.

```
f[x_, ITERATIONS_] := Sum[j*Exp[x*j], {j, 0, ITERATIONS}]/
  Sum[Exp[x*j], {j, 0, ITERATIONS}];

Plot[
 {Style[f[x, 10], Black, Thickness[0.002]], 
  Style[10, Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.001]]},
 {x, 0, 3.5},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.001]],
 FrameStyle -> Directive[ FontSize -> 18, Black, Thickness[0.002]],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 FrameLabel -> {Style[
    "x (= \[CurlyEpsilon] / \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(B\)]\)T)", 
    Black, FontSize -> 18], 
   Style["\[LeftAngleBracket]j\[RightAngleBracket]", Black, 
    FontSize -> 18]},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 3.5}, {4.5, 10.5}}, (* Here is the problem. *)
 FrameTicks -> {{{ {10 /2, 
      Style[N /2, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}, {10, 
      Style[N, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}}, None},  {{0}, None}}
 ]
```

**-0.39:**

[image]

**-0.38:**

[image]

I want to Plot this graph with a `PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 3.5}, {4.5, 10.5}}`, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A work-around: You can use `GridLines` and `GridLinesStyle` instead of `Axes -> True` and `AxesStyle`:

```
Plot[{Style[f[x, 10], Black, Thickness[0.002]], 
  Style[10, Dashed, Black, Thickness[0.001]]}, {x, 0, 3.5}, 
 GridLines -> {{0}, {}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.001]], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 18, Black, Thickness[0.002]], 
 ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x (= ε / \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(B\)]\)T)", 
    Black, FontSize -> 18], 
   Style["〈j〉", Black, FontSize -> 18]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 3.5}, {4.5, 10.5}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{10/2, Style[N/2, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}, 
     {10, Style[N, SingleLetterItalics -> False]}}, None}, {{0}, None}}]
```

[image]